# onestepcheckout and chrome autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete

I found on Stackexchange 1 similar question from feb 2016.
The solution offered then does not work anymore.

Chrome ignores all autocomplete="xxx" tags.
The problem is that all addresses are stored wrong.

Because Magento uses 2 fields for street and number, Chrome Autocompletes it wrong.

It should be: 
    Name
Street Number
Zipcode City

But Chrome makes it:
    Name
Street Number Street Number
Zipcode City

So now all variations of autocomplete="xxx" are ignored by Chrome, what can I do to prevent the wrong autocomplete?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance, John

Answer (score 2):

You can try the autocomplete="off" in your field.

If it does not work, try this fix:

```
<input id="email" readonly type="email" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) { this.removeAttribute('readonly');
// fix for mobile safari to show virtual keyboard
this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
```